# How do I move from a testing on heroku to production on a host like hostmonster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, heroku

How do I move from a testing on heroku to production on a host like hostmonster?

I have recently created my first web app using ROR and heroku to test on and with repositories on git hub. I have a site on hostmonster and would like to transition the web app so it sits on hostmonster. Is there a best practice for this sort of move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Hostmonster help page on rails: https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/rails

Here is a forum post on Rails on Hostmonster: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=38218

I'm not sure how configurable or optimized the experience is but there seems to be people running on Hostmaster successfully.  You'll be responsible for setting up your own database and modifying your `database.yml` file.  There's a bunch of things that Heroku (or any other PaaS) hosts provide by default.

Deploying your app to Hostmaster can be done using Capistrano or using `git pull` on the Heroku master repository.

Personally, even for my Heroku apps I keep a copy of my code on a private Github repo.